# SP/View for daily aggregation of 3-hours values

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

i'm trying to group 3-hours forecasting values into a daily table, The problem is that i need to process non standard group operations on values. I attach an example (provided by [Openweather](https://openweathermap.org/) ).

```
time                  temp  press   desc     w_sp w_dir
"2017-12-20 00:00:00" -4.49 1023.42 "clear"  1.21 198.501
"2017-12-20 03:00:00" -2.51 1023.63 "clouds" 1.22 180.501
"2017-12-20 06:00:00" -0.07 1024.43 "clouds" 1.53 169.503
"2017-12-20 09:00:00"  0.57 1024.83 "snow"   1.77 138.502
"2017-12-20 12:00:00"  0.95 1024.41 "snow"   1.61 271.001
"2017-12-20 15:00:00" -0.47 1024.17 "snow"   0.61 27.5019
"2017-12-20 18:00:00" -2.52 1024.52 "clear"  1.16 13.0007
"2017-12-20 21:00:00" -2.63 1024.73 "clear"  1.07 131.504
```

In my case i should evaluate the overall daily meteo description according to a mix of the top 2 occurence labels, and concerning wind direction i cannot AVG  the 8 values, i have to apply a specific formula.

I'm familiar with sql but not so much with postgres stored procedures, i think i need something like cursor but i'm a bit lost here. I'm sure this can be achieved in many ways but i'm asking you to give me the path. So far i have a draft of a stored procedure but i'm a bit clueless

```
CREATE FUNCTION meteo_forecast_daily () 
RETURNS TABLE (
forecasting_date DATE,
temperature NUMERIC,
pressure NUMERIC,
description VARCHAR(20),
w_speed NUMERIC,
w_dir NUMERIC
) 
AS $$
DECLARE 
clouds INTEGER;
snow INTEGER;
clear INTEGER;
rain INTEGER;
thunderstorm INTEGER;
BEGIN
 RETURN QUERY SELECT
 m.forecasting_time::date as forecasting_date,
 avg(m.temperature) as temperature
 avg(m.pressure) as pressure
 description???
 avg(m.w_sp) as w_speed
 w_dir????
 FROM
 meteo_forecast_last_update m
 WHERE
 forecasting_time > now()
 group by forecasting_date;
END; $$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Thus my question is, how can i retrieve the 8 elements for each date and process them somehow separately?

Desired result:

```
time          temp press    desc                    w_sp  w_dir
"2017-12-20" -4.49 1023.42 "clear,clouds,rain,..."  1.21 (198.501, 212.23..)
"2017-12-21" -4.49 1023.42 "rain,snow,rain,..."     1.45 (211.501, 112.26..)
"2017-12-22" -4.49 1023.42 "clear,clouds,rain,..."  1.89 (156.501, 312.53..)
```

Thanks in advance and happy new year :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should achieve this by

```
SELECT m.forecasting_time::date AS forecasting_date,
    AVG(m.temperature) as temperature,
    AVG(m.pressure) as pressure,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT m.description, ',') AS description,
    AVG(m.w_sp) as w_speed,
    ARRAY_AGG(m.w_dir) AS w_dir
FROM meteo_forecast_last_update m
WHERE m.forecasting_time > now()
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

You may use `DISTINCT` inside of an aggregate function. It applies the aggregate function only for distinct values.

Comment: sorry i didnt' explain myself properly: i need a record for each day, not 8 records, if i remove the group by 2 it gives the output correclty but string_agg (and array_agg which i used for wind_direction) aggregates every value, not just the 8 of the corresponding day

Comment: Sorry, I will adapt my post. `STRING_AGG` is an aggregate function like `AVG`. It only aggregates the strings per group and not more. Do you mean distinct values? You may use the `DISTINCT` modifier for aggregates.

Comment: It's ok to not use DISTINCT since i need the number of occurrencuies of each meteo description. Thanks man :)